# Paypal intergration with REST sdk for advanced operations

Tags: rest, paypal, sdk, recurring-billing

I want use paypal with rest sdk to perform some operations , I am following [rest sdk api documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) for it.

> Using rest sdk api, an I perform recurring billing,expressCheckout
>   and many more advanced operations?
>
> Is there are any sample examples or api documentation are provided by
>   paypal for it?

```
I have gone through rest sdk api documentation but didin't get any
```

example or documentation for recurring billing.

If anybody has used paypal rest sdk for advanced paypal operations then please give me some suggestions for how to use them efficiently?

Thanks,

Comment: You linked to their documentation which has sample code for every function and lists every function available to you. This is far too broad of a "question" anyway

Comment: yes I agree @Ghost,but at least I am searching for good example for recurring process.Have you seen any good sample example for it?